# Doctrine Nothing to update after adding onDelete="CASCADE"

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to add the option `onDelete="CASCADE"` on one of my attributes via the `@JoinColumn` annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product",mappedBy="category",fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $products;
```

But when I try to update with `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` , I always get:

> nothing to uptade - database already sync.

I tried to add some other attributes and I got the same issue. However, if I intentionally add a mistake I get an error as expected.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@OneToMany` annotation is the one you use on the inverse side of your many-to-one association. The table storing the entities on this side of the association does not hold any foreign key pointing to the table storing your `Product` entities, thus there is no "join column" there.

[The documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn) states the following about `@JoinColumn`:

> This annotation is used in the context of relations in @ManyToOne, @OneToOne fields and in the Context of @JoinTable nested inside a @ManyToMany.

In your case, the annotation does not apply to any column at all and consequently, your database does not need to be updated.

If you wish to have `Product` entities related to a given `Category` removed through cascade operations by your database, you have to add a `@JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")` on the owning side of the association, next to the `@ManyToOne` annotation of the `category` attribute of `Product`.

Comment: Glad to have helped ;) If you wish, you can mark the answer as accepted as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)